# Why ModelDriven has stopped working in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, model-driven, valuestack

I have used `ModelDriven` in my `Action` class, previously it was working fine, now it has stopped working.

When I used `<s:debug>` tag of Struts in my JSP I found following result:

**Struts `ValueStack` Debug:**

[image: Struts ValueStack Debug]

I'm accessing values in my JSP page as :

```
<s:property value="categoryName"/>
<s:property value="categoryId"/>       // I typed here
```

working fine, If I accessed them as :

```
<s:property value="category.categoryName"/>
<s:property value="category.categoryId"/>
```

**My questions are :**

1. Why I'm getting properties 2 times ?
2. How to avoid them getting multiple times ?
3. I have saw many people suggesting to avoid `ModelDriven`, why ?

**Update:**

1. Actually I'm getting properties 3 times, I forgot to highlight 3rd one. Please look at my `Action` class.
2. I have not defined separate properties of `Model` class in my action, **highlighted by 1**,  how to set these properties ?
3. Is *anything*, I'm doing wrong when implementing `ModelDriven` ?

**Here is my model in `CategoryAction`:**

```
public class CategoryAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Category>,
                                Preparable, SessionAware, ServletRequestAware, ServletContextAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Category category;
    private Category [] categories;

    private ServletContext servletContext;
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private ServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public Category getModel() {
        return this.category;
    }
    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        this.category = new Category();
        if( this.jmain == null )
            this.jmain = new Jmain();
    }
    public void prepareCrudCategory() throws Exception {
        this.categoryService = new CategoryService();
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("----------CategoryAction#execute()-----------");
        if( this.category.getCategoryId() == 0)
            this.category = this.jmain.getCategory( 1 );        //Get Main Category
        else
            this.category = this.jmain.getCategory( this.category.getCategoryId() );
        System.out.println(this.category.toString());
        return super.execute();
    }


    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public Category[] getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
    public void setCategories(Category[] categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

**Update 2:**

**This is my JSP code snippet:**

```
<form action="add-category" id="id-add-id-entry-form" name="addIdEntry" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="opType" name="opType" value='<s:property value="opType"/>'> 

    <br /> <br />
    <center>
        <span id="id-message-span">
            <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
                <h3 style="font-size: 22px; color: #FD0006; text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); margin-left: 330px;">
                    <s:actionmessage />
                </h3>
            </s:if>
            <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
                <h3 style="font-size: 16px; color: #FD0006; text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); margin-left: 330px;">
                    <s:actionerror />
                </h3>
            </s:if>
        </span>
        <div id="id-id-entry-div" class="class-id-entry-div class-center">
            <fieldset style="height: 100%; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; border-color: #FEC458;"
                        >
                <legend class="PageTitleUpperCase"> Add Category </legend>
                <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="65%" class="class-center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="color: red">*</span>
                            <label class="Label_Green"> Patent Category Name :</label>
                            <s:if test=""></s:if>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <s:property value="opType"/><br>
                            <s:property value="categoryId"/>
                            <s:property value="categoryName"/>
                            <s:if test="%{opType == 0}">
                                <%-- <s:property value="categoryName"/> --%>
                                <input type="hidden" name="parentCategoryId" value='<s:property value="categoryId"/>' >
                                <label class="Label_Green">
                                    <s:property value="categoryName"/>
                                </label>
                            </s:if>
                            <s:else>
                                <%-- <s:property value="parentCategoryName"/> --%>
                                <input type="hidden" name="parentCategoryId" value='<s:property value="parentCategoryId"/>' >
                                <label class="Label_Green">
                                    <s:property value="parentCategoryName"/>
                                </label>
                            </s:else>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="color: red">*</span>
                            <label class="Label_Green"> Category Name :</label>
                            <s:if test=""></s:if>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <input type="hidden" name="categoryId" 
                                <s:if test="%{opType == 0}">value='0'</s:if>
                                <s:else>value='<s:property value="categoryId"/>'</s:else>
                            >
                                 
                            <input id="id-category-name-text" type="text" name="categoryName"
                                required="required" size="40" placeholder="Enter Category Name Here..."
                                <s:if test="%{opType == 1}">value='<s:property value="categoryName"/>'</s:if> >
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="submit" id="submit_img"
                            <s:if test="opType != 0"> value='Update'</s:if>
                            <s:else> value='Submit' </s:else> >
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <s:debug/>
    </center>
</form>
```

**How I got `ValueStack` Contents Using Debug Tag:**

After using `<s:debug/>`, I got `[debug]` link on clicking it, following values are shown :

[image: Value Stack Contents Using Debug Tag]

`<s:debug/>` for List Category Page, `[debug]` link on clicking it , following values are shown :

[image: List Category Page]

Comment: ModelDriven pushes the model onto the top of the value stack after pushing the action. The action properties, e.g., `model`, are still there--it doesn't push the model *instead* of the action. I generally avoid ModelDriven for all but the simplest cases because I haven't found it to be overly-helpful.

Comment: @DaveNewton plz check my update, and how to set properties at **highlighted by 1** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) pushes the model onto the `top` of the `ValueStack`, so you have both a model and action in the stack.

`ValueStack` is an interface implemented by Struts framework that allows to manipulate data while the request is processed. How it works you can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20425283/573032).

You can find properties with the same name/key on the different levels of the `ValueStack`, the order of searching is from the `top` to down the stack until the value is found.

`ModelDriven` action simplifies mapping form fields to the model object, but you might have difficulties if you need to do multiple models to the same action class.

You might have difficulties with validation, type conversion, other features of the Struts framework that work with interceptors.

And if you can't resolve your problems rather than removing `ModelDriven` from the implemented interfaces or reconfiguring the interceptor stack to disable [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html), then you can live without `ModelDriven`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130398/discussion-on-answer-by-roman-c-modeldriven-stopped-working-in-struts2).